# How do I use Console.ReadLine() in an if statement?

Tags: c#, console

```
static void DelayText(string text, int delay = 1000) {
    if (Console.ReadLine()) {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
        else {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to create a method that automatically takes text input and delays it by a certain amount, but if a key is pressed it just writes the text instantly.

I know the error, and why it's happening

`` main.cs(83,15): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `bool' ``

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: "that automatically takes text input and delays it by a certain amount, but if a key is pressed it just writes the text instantly." - uuhm.. what? could you please be _a lot_ more precise about what you want to happen?

Comment: I think I was precise enough. It takes text, and types it out after a delay. If a key is pressed the text is typed out immediately. There's not much more to elaborate on.

Comment: I guess the requirement is clear. OP wants to stop execution until either the key was pressed or the delay time is over. In both cases the text should be written to the console. Since a console application has no real `KeyPress` event i dont know an easy solution which also covers the delay-time.

Answer (score 0):

The Console.ReadLine() returns a string.
An If statement checks for boolean.

If you want to work with `Console.ReadLine()` in an if statement.

You need to check for equality in the if statement.

for example

```
if(Console.ReadLine() == "John Smith") //this returns true if the string that was inputted is John Smith
```

If the string that was inputted is John Smith then the condition is met and the if statement would work.

If the string is any other string, like `"Mark Owen"` the else statement will be executed.

Even if you will make an input of `"JOHN SMITH"` the else statement will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You will find your optimized code below

```
static void DelayText(string text, int delay = 1000)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Console.ReadLine()))
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
   Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```